# Can "or else" be replaced with "as otherwise"?

Tags: conjunctions, parts-of-speech

I just had a doubt regarding the actual usage of "or else" and "as otherwise", while joining sentences.

> Henry should hurry up. He will miss his bus.

Please tell me which of these answers is correct for joining the above sentences:

> Henry should hurry up, as otherwise he will miss his bus.
>
> Henry should hurry up, or else he will miss his bus.
>
> Henry should hurry up, he will miss his bus otherwise.
>
> Henry should hurry up, he will miss his bus or else.

Also, can a workaround be suggested, so that no ambiguity remains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Henry should hurry up. He will miss his bus.

Nothing wrong with this construction. It's meaning is clear. No grammatical reason to join the two sentences.

> Henry should hurry up, as otherwise he will miss his bus.

Nothing wrong with this either, although it's not obvious that this is preferable to two sentences.

> Henry should hurry up, or else he will miss his bus.

Ditto the previous comment.

> Henry should hurry up, he will miss his bus otherwise.

According to Strunk and White, this is incorrect. One shouldn't link independent clauses not joined by a conjunction with a comma (*The Elements of Style*, Macmillan 1979, pp. 5-7). Instead, in general one should use a semicolon or a period. Opting for a semicolon (because *otherwise* links the two clauses together):

- "Henry should hurry up; he will miss his bus otherwise."

> Henry should hurry up, he will miss his bus or else.

This sentence has the same problem as the previous example: it lacks a punctuation mark between the two independent clauses. Opting again for the semicolon:

- "Henry should hurry up; he will miss his bus or else."

But this, too, is incorrect. *Or else* doesn't make sense at the end of  the second independent clause. Dropping *or else*, one obtains the following:

- "Henry should hurry up; he will miss his bus."

I wouldn't say this is wrong, but because the relationship between the first and second clauses is weak (for example, there is no *otherwise* linking the two), it seems to me that two separate sentences would be preferable.

Comment: The word 'else' can be omitted and still retain the meaning, at least in Br English. This gives "Henry should hurry up or he will miss his bus."

Comment: @BoldBen Absolutely. That would be fine.